# Powershell - VBoxManage Cloning Script

Tags: powershell, virtualbox

I wrote a powershell script to read data from a text file, and then clone a virtual machine, using VBoxManage. It works, however, it reports back with this error.

```
[string]$vmPath = "C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\"
[string]$vmName="QuestionMark"
[string]$vBoxClonevdi = "clonehd"
[string]$vBoxVMName = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\log.txt"
[string]$invokeCommand 
[string]$filetype=".vdi"
[string]$vBoxManagewithQuotes= "`"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe`"" 



if(Test-Path ("C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox VMs\log.txt")){

    [int]$ConvertNum = -1
    [int]::TryParse($vBoxVMName.Substring(16), [ref]$ConvertNum)

    Write-Output ("Version Number: " + $ConvertNum)
    $ConvertAfter = $ConvertNum + 1
    Write-Output ("New Version: " + $ConvertAfter)

    $vmOut = $vmPath+$vmName+$ConvertAfter+$filetype
    $vmToClone=($vmPath+$vmName+$ConvertNum+$fileType)
    $write= ($vmName + $ConvertAfter)  

}

if(Test-Path ("C:\Users\someuser\cloneVM.bat")){

     cmd.exe /c  "C:\Users\someuser\cloneVM.bat" $vmName $ConvertAfter 

}
```

Error:

```
cmd.exe : 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
At C:\Users\someuser\clonevdi.ps1:28 char:6
+      cmd.exe /c  "C:\Users\someuser\cloneVM.bat" $vmName $ConvertAfter
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0%...10%...20%....0%...90%...100%:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I'm not sure what this error means. What does it mean? and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like it is trying to use progress output of the script and execute it? What happens when you void all output `[void](cmd.exe /c  "C:\Users\someuser\cloneVM.bat" $vmName $ConvertAfter )`?

Comment: Maybe that progress comes out the error stream which is why you see what you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that what you are seeing is `cloneVM.bat` sending data to the error stream and PowerShell is meerly reporting the error. I can simulate this with the following bat file

```
'GAME OVER MAN! GAME OVER' 1>&2
```

And calling that bat file from PowerShell

```
cmd.exe /c C:\temp\test.bat
```

Which triggers the following error in PowerShell

```
cmd.exe : 'GAME OVER MAN! GAME OVER' 
At line:1 char:1
+ cmd.exe /c C:\temp\test.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('GAME OVER MAN! GAME OVER' :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

One way to handle this would be to send the error to the output stream and just capture it into a variable. This would be the preferred method if you needed other output from `cloneVM.bat`. You can look into other option with [about_Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx)

```
$return = cmd.exe /c C:\temp\test.bat 2>&1
```

If you were to look at `cloneVM.bat` I would venture an educated guess that you will find some lines with `2>&1`

Comment: Thanks for the help. What I want to know is, why the error? Running VBoxManage from command prompt works great. Only from powershell does this occur. Seeing as you were able to reproduce the error with your own batch file, what's going on with CMD and Powershell?

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield It common to produce messages in the error stream for the end user. PSEXEC uses it for the beginning information. This is not anything wrong per sei. Since PowerShell is the calling application it wants to present those errors. Look in that batch file for error redirection. I'm sure its there